# Excel 2013 Add-in in Visual Studio 2017 Express

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vsto

Is it possible to create an Excel 2013 Add in Visual Studio 2017 Express? I can only see Excel Web addin. Is there still something like VSTO for Visual Studio 2017 Express? If so can you please point me to the download link?

Comment: Not sure why someone would down-vote this?! Anyway I found the solution. thanks to @Lukas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a local AddIn your Require the VSTO Template.

Download the ProjectTemplate at

https://www.visualstudio.com/de/vs/office-tools/

or open the Visual Studio Installer and add "Office- /SharePoint" in the "Web and Cloud" Section.

It install the VSTO Project Template too.

Comment: Thanks I was aware of this link (not the German though (-:). However, I just cannot see a link to download the ProjectTemplate for VSTO - especially for VS 2017 Express.

Comment: Actually the suggestion using the VS installer works fine. How could I not have seen this part? Thanks!